# THe novalidate attribute of bootstrap is not working on my app. after using this my app get crashed

Tags: node.js, forms, express, backend, ejs

I used novalidate for custom validation but novalidate is not working, I also linked js code of the bootstrap.

When I remove this novalidate attribute the form give response as a default browser. but when I put this on my form and try to submit invalid info the app crashed in the terminal and page give me error.